# Getting Emscripten streaming audio to work

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to get SoLoud audio engine working with Emscripten, and it's acting rather strangely. As an experiment, I'm playing a 500ms sine wave.

With a 2048 sample buffer, the latency is around a second or more, and what comes out is 25ms of sine wave. If I reduce the buffer down to 256 samples, the latency gets a bit better (still bad), and the output grows to around, but not exactly, 500ms, and the sound is not clean by any means. This was with firefox; chrome is silent.

The emscripten/tests/sdl_audio* tests all use sdl_mixer instead of the stream directly.

So my question is - is there any way to get streaming audio (so that I do my own mixing and feed sample buffers to some API) to work under emscripten?

Comment: As an update, emscripten and browsers have improved so much after I posted this question that it's in the "almost works" category, instead of "totally broken". No openal needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's a pull request for emscripten to make the SDL implementation use the Web Audio API (it currently uses the Mozilla Audio API, which is why Chrome was silent): https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/1299 In that same pull request, I believe there were many improvements made to the buffer streaming support.

Otherwise, the OpenAL implementation uses Web Audio and has buffer streaming support currently in the master branch.

Comment: I'll probably have to make an OpenAL back-end at some point in any case, so that may be the best way to approach it.. I just hope it works better than the mozilla audio api =)

Comment: Made the OpenAL back-end. Emscripted, both firefox and chrome fail; firefox at alGenBuffers and chrome at alGenSources, which makes zero sense, as those functions pretty much can't fail. Oh well, I tried. I'll wait for the webaudio patch to get in and hope that fixes the sound..